# Is there a way in C to copy all the files of a directory to another directory?

Tags: c, file, copy

I'm hoping not to resort to reading and writing of every file. Isn't there any other approach to this which might be a little shorter and easier?
I'm looking to do this on a linux machine.

Comment: Hmmm ... `system("cp path/to/source/* path/to/destin/");`

Comment: There is no easy way in C, you need to write the code yourself or use the `system` function which lets you do basically anything you can do in a shell

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why do you need to do this in a C program? What is the actual and underlying problem you attempt to solve? Please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: It isn't particularly difficult to write code in C that will copy files, and isn't particularly difficult to write code in C that will iterate directories. If you organize it well, you'll probably only have to write this code once (for C) in your working life. Why not just do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [system()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/)

> system() is used to invoke an operating system command from a C/C++
> program.

On windows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    return system("copy .\\CopyFrom\\*  .\\CopyTo");
}
```

Compile and run. Voilà!

[image]

---

On linux you'd do something like

```
return system("cp ./CopyFrom/*  ./CopyTo");
```

Comment: While I'm sure this will work fine, it does rely on their being a shell or command-line processor available. But the bigger problem, I think, is getting feedback during the copy, if you're not writing a console program.